# two columns in Angular 11

Tags: html, css

thats a real beginner question, and i tried so many examples out there.
but i cant get it run to get two comums with responsible design (means no pixels).

my [prototypes](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ygjpwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) always show only 1 column.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ygjpwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

i tried:

```html
<div layout="col-sm" md-content layout-padding>
  <div class="col-sm">
    One
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    two
  </div>
</div>
```

and i tried:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      two
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use flexbox to achieve that

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vdawy6

```css
    .col{display:flex;}
    .col div{flex:1}
    .col1{background:red}
    .col2{background:blue; color:white}
```

```html
    <div class="col">
      <div class="col1">1</div>
      <div class="col2">2</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thats looks perfect. how can it get the source?

Comment: yours source give me: `Error in src/app/app.component.html (31:1)`

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ you can play with this :)

Comment: please find the source here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vdawy6

Comment: I have added the full source in my answer ;)

Comment: yes ty. i think i need much more time. looks surprisingly complicated. i tried do thisin the html, but probably not allowed to to this in the html-file  https://gist.github.com/sl5net/7ab65a10451ac33c53d5150c36436080#file-src_index-html

Answer (score 2):

You can import bootstrap and use class "col-sm".

config/install that before:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-first-project
cd my-first-project/
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

copy into

`~/ng-bootstrap/my-first-project/src/app/app.component.html` :

```
<div class="content" role="main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        1 of 2 columns
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        1 of 2 columns
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

run it:

`ng serve`